# Using Ukrainian Char-set in html

Tags: char

I'm sure this is a ridiculously basic question, but I haven't been able to find anything to explain it to me. My site needs an English and Ukrainian version, and the English version is already coded. I just don't know how to tell the html document to display Ukrainian characters for the Ukrainian part of the site. Any help is humbly accepted by an amateur coder.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your html head
`<meta charset="UTF-8" />`

and make sure all texts (in your db or whatever) are encoded utf-8